# how to return value from observable http request and store it in local variable?

Tags: angular, http, observable

I have a Url `http://localhost:3000/users/1` that will return json:

```
{ "id": 1, "name": "David", "is_available": true }
```

then I want to make a method that return **is_available** (boolean). But this method below will return undefined. This seems weird for me that new to angular & observable.

```
checkIsAvailable(id): boolean {
        let available;
        http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/1').subscribe(user => {
                available = user.is_available;
        }
        return available;
}
```

If I console.log() inside the .subscribe(), **user.is_available** will return true. How to properly create method that return value from http request?

Answer (score 0):

```
checkIsAvailable(id): Observable<boolean>{
        let available;
        return http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/1').pipe(map(user => {
                return user.is_available;
        }));
}
```

Subscribe in component

```
this.service.checkIsAvailable().subscribe((res)=>this.available = res);
```

Comment: It seems like I have to store the is_available value on the class instance/variable. Is there any chance to store it in the local variable? so i can create a method that return boolean instead of observable<boolean>.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

it seems you can only return `Promise` from an async function

try the following

```
async checkIsAvailable(id): Promise<any> {
        return await http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/1').toPromise();
}
```

change the way you call this function

```
this.checkIsAvailable(id).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);

  // your code here

}
```

Comment: compilation error. Type 'boolean' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.ts(1055)